# Best way to convert std::wstring to QString

Tags: c++, qt, qstring, wstring

I'm currently working on a larger project, where the "logic" is implemented in standard C++ with all strings being handled with `std::wstring` and the UI part is implemented using Qt and thus necessarily `QString` (Bonus question: is this true?).

What is the best way to connect those two worlds?

I know I can use something like

```
std::wstring wideString;
QString qtString = QString::fromStdWString(wideString);
```

but I'm wondering if there is a nicer way with less typing involved. A user defined operator came to my mind, but I'm not experienced enough to tackle that on my own.

Would be glad if anyone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: Have you ever read [QString, std::wstring and built-in wchar_t](http://qt-project.org/wiki/toStdWStringAndBuiltInWchar)?

Comment: You've accepted an answer which described only the conversion in one direction. Was that your question? Then you should probably modify the title so that it is not misleading (for those hoping to find an answer about the conversion in the other direction).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It's a good idea to use `QString::fromStdWString` **but** (!!!) if Qt was compiled with exactly the same STL headers as your project. If not - you can get a lot of fun, catching a bug.

If you don't sure that both STL headers are the same use `QString::fromWCharArray`:

```
std::wstring wideString;
QString qtString = QString::fromWCharArray( wideString.c_str() );
```

**Update:** answering to @juzzlin:
Lets imagine that Qt was build with the STL containing the following `std::wstring`:

```
class wstring { // I know, that there's no such class, but I'm shure you'll understand what I want to say
    wchar_t * m_ptr;
    size_t m_length;
    ...
};
```

and you have the STL containing the following `std::wstring`:

```
class wstring {
    wchar_t * m_ptr;
    wchar_t * m_the_end;
    ...
};
```

If you'll give your `std::wstring` to Qt, it will interpret `m_the_end` pointer as the length of the string, and

> you can get a lot of fun, catching a bug

Comment: What would happen if "exactly the same" STL headers are not used? And why is QString::fromWCharArray() a better solution is that case?

Comment: fromStdWString is inlined in qstring.h and has implementation: `return fromWCharArray(s.data(), int(s.size()));` So, it is safe to use it.

Comment: @rmflow Yes, you're right, but there's no guarantee that `wstring::data` and `wstring::size` are inlined too.

Comment: @borisbn it does not matter, since they are compiled from header (in your code). You could write by yourself `fromWCharArray(s.data(), int(s.size()));` instead of calling `fromStdWString` and result would be the same.

Comment: @borisbn, could you update the answer, please?

Answer (score 2):

I think a user defined conversion is what you're looking for, and from what I can gather, it should look something like this:

```
class foo
{
public:
   operator QString(std::wstring& ws)
   {
       return QString::fromStdWString(ws);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe make a inline function `QString toQString(std::wstring string)` to make it 'less to type' ...

but to be honest ... thats not the big effort at all to write it from time to time ;)

soo long zai